# Stringify key-value pairs in dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have made a dictionary which contains two values: a `DateTime` and a `string`.

Now I want to print everything from the dictionary to a Textbox.
Does anybody know how to do this?

I have used this code to print the dictionary to the console:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Dictionary<DateTime, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<DateTime, string>();
    dictionary.Add(monthCalendar1.SelectionStart, textBox1.Text);

    foreach (KeyValuePair<DateTime, string> kvp in dictionary)
    {
        //textBox3.Text += ("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
        Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: what about the line you have commented out?

Comment: That gives the following error: Only assignement, call, increment, await and new object expressions can be used as a statement.

Comment: I think you're just missing a `string.Format` in the commented out line.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Just to close this

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<DateTime, string> kvp in dictionary)
{
    //textBox3.Text += ("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
    Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
}
```

Changes to this

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<DateTime, string> kvp in dictionary)
{
    //textBox3.Text += ("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
    textBox3.Text += string.Format("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 97):

Cleaner way using LINQ:

```
var lines = dictionary.Select(kvp => kvp.Key + ": " + kvp.Value.ToString());
textBox3.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines);
```

`kvp` is short for "key-value pair".

Comment: [with $ - string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) `kvp => $"{kvp.Key}:{kvp.Value}"`

Answer (score 28):

There's more than one way to stringify a dictionary; here's my solution:

1. Use Select() to convert the key-value pair to a string;
2. Convert to a list of strings;
3. Write out to the console using ForEach().

```
dict.Select(i => $"{i.Key}: {i.Value}").ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Answer (score 20):

There are so many ways to do this, here is some more:

```
string.Join(Environment.NewLine, dictionary.Select(a => $"{a.Key}: {a.Value}"))
```

```
dictionary.Select(a => $"{a.Key}: {a.Value}{Environment.NewLine}")).Aggregate((a,b)=>a+b)
```

```
new String(dictionary.SelectMany(a => $"{a.Key}: {a.Value} {Environment.NewLine}").ToArray())
```

Additionally, you can then use one of these and encapsulate it in an extension method:

```
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static string ToReadable<T,V>(this Dictionary<T, V> d){
        return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, d.Select(a => $"{a.Key}: {a.Value}"));
    }   
}
```

And use it like this: `yourDictionary.ToReadable()`.

Comment: Isnt it kind of a shame that you cant print lists/collections just like that?

Comment: This is beautiful, thank you:

string.Join(Environment.NewLine, dictionary.Select(a => $"{a.Key}: {a.Value}"))

Answer (score 4):

My goto is

```
Console.WriteLine( Serialize(dictionary.ToList() ) );
```

Make sure you include the package `using static System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer;`

Comment: I also needed to add `using System.Linq` for the `.ToList()`