# Easy way to Print Values of a dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have the below code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Add 5 Employees to a Dictionary.
    var Employees = new Dictionary<int, Employee>();
    Employees.Add(1, new Employee(1, "John"));
    Employees.Add(2, new Employee(2, "Henry"));
    Employees.Add(3, new Employee(3, "Jason"));
    Employees.Add(4, new Employee(4, "Ron"));
    Employees.Add(5, new Employee(5, "Yan"));
}
```

Is there an easy way to print the values of the dictionaries in an easy way like in Java? For example, I want to be able to print something like:

> Employee with key 1: Id=1, Name= John
>
> Employee with key 2: Id=2, Name= Henry

.. etc..

Thank you.

Sorry, am used to Java!

Comment: Well sure, you can loop over them easily, printing each entry. What have you tried, and what happened? If you don't want to put the loop more than once, you can write a method to do that...

Comment: Why do you have a Java tag if this question is about C#?

Comment: Did you get it to work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# - Print dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28552603/c-sharp-print-dictionary)

Comment: Yes, I got it to work. Thanks to all. Sorry about the java tag, was a mistake!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use foreach statement:

```
foreach(var pair in Employees)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Employee with key {pair.Key}: Id={pair.Value.Id} Name={pair.Value.Name}");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try using the `foreach`:

```
foreach (var res in Employees)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Employee with key {0}: ID = {1}, Name = {2}", res.Key, res.Value.Id, res.Value.Name);
}
```

or, simply using LINQ:

```
var output = String.Join(", ", Employees.Select(res => "Employee with key " + res.Key + ": ID = " + res.Value.Id + ", Name = " + res.Value.Name));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the foreach loop to print all the value inside the Dictionary.

```
foreach(var employe in Employees) {
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Employee with key {0}: Id={1}, Name= {2}",employe.Key, employe.Value.Id, employe.Value.Name ));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define an `IDictionary` reference, and make it point to a `Dictionary` object

```
IDictionary<int, Employee> employees = new Dictionary<int,Employee>();
employees.Add(1, new Employee(1, "John"));
//add the rest of the employees
```

to loop through the dictionary, you can use

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<int, Employee> entry in employees)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Employee with key "+entry.Key+": Id="+entry.Value.GetId()+", Name= "+entry.Value.GetName());
}
```

This is similar to Java's `HashMap<>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var items = Employees.Select(kvp => string.Format("Employee with key {0} : Id={1}, Name={2}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value.Id, kvp.Value.Name);

var text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, items);
```