# How to Deserialize this JSON file

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, firebase, json-deserialization

I am facing this problem to convert this JSON File. Anybody please tell me how to deserialize this JSON file.
https://fasp-ee999.firebaseio.com/Students.json?auth=yB71DWGpZeBBQjvtEvc4yeROXO8zp717W180rlzw

Above is my json file

Comment: What language are you using? Most languages have some form of "Deserialize" method that will do this job for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get formatted JSON in .NET using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661063/how-do-i-get-formatted-json-in-net-using-c)

Comment: No, i don't need to format I need to deserialize it

Comment: Check the answer of Edwards Link, not the question.

Comment: @jdickel I want to deserialize set of objects into a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a dictionary, sample with .net core 3.1:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Data
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dataToDeserialize = File.ReadAllText("Students.json");

            var deserializedResult = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Data>>(dataToDeserialize);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bro, you helped me a lot. Thank you so much much but. I want to print those JSON objects how do I do. if I use for each statement and student.value then I am not getting the objects correctly. please help me in this situation also, please

Comment: Bro I want to download a string from the internet then I want to deserialize how can I do this

Comment: @InfiniteCoders: [Download from Internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10928528/receiving-json-data-back-from-http-request/10928807), [Print a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28552603/c-sharp-print-dictionary)