# how do i read yaml key/value pair in C#?

Tags: c#, yaml

this is what i have

```
public void ConfigHandler()
{
    var deserializer = new YamlDotNet.Serialization.DeserializerBuilder()
        .WithNamingConvention(CamelCaseNamingConvention.Instance)
        .Build();
    var Config = deserializer.Deserialize<Configuration>(File.ReadAllText("filepath"));
    Console.WriteLine(Config.parameters.ToString());
}

class Configuration
{
    public List<Dictionary<string, string>> parameters { get; set; }
}
```

when i run this it just says: **System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]]**

here is the yaml file:

```
parameters:
- firstKey: value1
- secondKey: value2
```

what i would like to do is allow the user to add/remove key/value pairs in the yaml file and the program would be able to list them all

Comment: The `Config.parameters` is a dictionary. You can access to specific key like this;
Config.parameters["firstKey"]

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28552792/12473121

Comment: i tried this      
`foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in Config.parameters)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);

            }
        }

        class Configuration
        {
            public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> parameters { get; set; }
        }`
but it now gives an **exception unhandled** error.

Comment: sorry, new to stack overflow so im not sure how everything here works

Answer (score 0):

solved:

```
foreach (Dictionary<string, string> kvp in Config.parameters)
{
    string values = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, kvp.Select(a => $"{a.Key}: {a.Value}"));
    Console.WriteLine(values);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?